# Is a locally integrable function vanishing outside compacts bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that it vanishes outside a compact interval $[-C,C]$. Its also known that $f$ is locally summable(absolutely integrable in every bounded region of $\mathbb{R}$).

I can neither prove it nor come up with a counterexample. Any hints on how to prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f=(1/x^{1/2})\chi_{(0,1]}$ may work as a counterexample.